# How to render bound icons inside buttons?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, font-awesome

Say,
I have a group of buttons that I consider as a whole component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-for="button in buttonsGroup">{{button.icon}}</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

The props is "buttonsGroup" object:

```
export default {
    name: 'buttonsGroup',
    props: ['buttonsGroup']
}
```

When I use the component I have a list of buttons with icons like:

```
data(){
  return {
    iconButtons: [
                    {
                        icon: '<i class="fas fa-smile"></i>',
                    },
                    {
                        icon: '<i class="fas fa-sad-tear"></i>',
                    }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then use in the layot:

```
<buttons-group v-bind:buttonsGroup="iconButtons"></buttons-group>
```

As a result, I see the list of buttons, but instead of icons inside the buttons I see them as a text.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the html directive to insert html content

```
<button v-for="button in buttonsGroup" v-html="button.icon" />
```

But a better approach might be to just supply the icon name to the component

```
<button v-for="button in buttonsGroup">
    <i :class="'fas ' + button.icon">
</button>
```

and

```
iconButtons: [
    {icon: "fa-smile"},
    {icon: "fa-sad-tear"}
]
```

Comment: This is correct. Just be mindful when using `v-html` that you could expose yourself for `Cross-site scripting` attacks if there's a way for the user to input text that will be rendered by the `v-html` tag.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño yeah, I'm not going to get these data from a user, it's my own inner list. Thanks!

Comment: I added an alternative suggestion to the original answer

Comment: @StephenThomas thanks for the idea. Currently, I want to set up the whole icon but maybe will use this approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation section on raw HTML: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

By default, the double braces will render as text, but you can add the v-html flag for it to render.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that the "group of buttons" component doesn't has any state to watch so it's a perfect case for a [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components).

So you can achieve it like this:

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <button v-for="(button, index) of props.buttonsGroup"
          :key="index"
          v-html="button.icon" 
          v-on="listeners" <!-- In case you want to listen to button events -->
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

And in the script:

```
export default {
  props: {
    buttonsGroup: Array
  }
}
```